# Adding banner advert, findViewById giving "not enough information to infer type variable."

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

So I have my 1st app working sweet, I am trying to add banner ads and followed the walk through.

My main activity xml just holds a nav_host_fragment so I put the banner xml in that fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ButtonFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lightSwitch"
        android:layout_width="258dp"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/light_switch"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_light_on"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

According to the walk through the main activity needs to load the ads with

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
        
    }
```

But I am getting an error on findviewById of "not enough information to infer type variable." I am a bit stuck, any hep greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the banner view is defined in the fragment's xml, but you are trying to find the view in activity, so android studio is not detecting the type automatically.

assuming you are defining and showing the fragment in activity's xml, and your main_activity looks like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <fragment
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment "
       android:name="com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

you need to explicitly state the type of the view, so update
`mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)`
to
`mAdView = findViewById<AdView>(R.id.adView)`

remember to import AdView in activivty

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had to do as you suggested and move my XML to the activities XML.